# How to access variable from if statement inside else statement

Tags: python, flask, itsdangerous

I'm making simple flask login website using itsdangerous to have email verification.
When user register i create a token which i assign to reg_token column inside my database and send it as a link to users email. After user clicks the link I change reg_token value to "activated" so I can tell user that his account is already activated.
My problem is when token will expire. After it expires I can show that token has expired, but I would like to also show if account is activated even though token has expired, so user will know where's the problem.

```
@app.route('/confirm_email/<token>')
def confirm_email(token):
    try:
        email = s.loads(token, salt='email-confirm', max_age = 20)
        user_info = db.checkRegToken(email)
        if user_info[3] != 'activated':
            db.reg_token(email)
            return render_template('confirm_email.html')
        else:
            flash('Your account is already activated')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    except BadTimeSignature:
        message = Markup("<p>Your token has expired or is invalid. <a href='/resend'>click</a> here to resend</p>")
        flash(message)
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

I've tried to make `email = s.loads(token, salt='email-confirm', max_age = 20)` outside `try` statement so that I can also acces it in except statement, but it didn't work. I also tried to make it `global` but also failed.

I wonder if there's any way i can acces `email` variable from try statement inside my except statement.

I would like to make something like this but the email variable is created inside `try` statement and i can not access it

```
    except BadTimeSignature:
        user_info = db.checkRegToken(email)                  
        if user_info[3] == 'activated':
            flash('Your account is already activated')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            message = Markup("<p>Your token has expired or is invalid. <a href='/resend'>click</a> here to resend</p>")
            flash(message)
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Comment: "I've tried to make `email = s.loads(token, salt='email-confirm', max_age = 20)` outside try statement so that I can also acces it in except statement, but it didn't work" - how exactly did it fail?

Comment: @matszwecja I if create it outsie try statement my Except statement doesnt work, and it crush saying  'itsdangerous.exc.SignatureExpired: Signature age 2159 > 20 seconds'

Comment: If your token is expired, consider it gone, completely. Do not rely on this token or on any data related to it. So, you have an unauthorized request →no user → no email address.

Comment: As Klaus said. If this `s.loads(...` is a line that fails then `email` was *never created*. It doesn't exist and therefore there is no way of accessing it.